# Mecanismo subir y bajar de nivel en Python

Tags: python, while

Estoy teniendo problemas en algo que tal vez sea sencillo para ustedes, estoy tratando de crear un código que suba y baje de nivel, ganando puntos de experiencia, ejemplo, la variable VAL es la que recibe los puntos y la variable MAX es la cantidad de experiencia a obtener, cada vez que VAL llega a igualar o pasar a MAX, entonces la variable NV sube un nivel, y MAX aumenta también el nivel máximo de experiencia para que cada vez sea mas difícil subir de nivel, mi problema es que deseo que el mecanismo funcione también a la inversa, ósea que se puedan restar puntos, y decrecer de nivel, lo mismo debe ocurrir de forma inversa, pero de forma negativa, si se llega al nivel 0, para pasar al nivel -1 el VAL o valor tendría que ser mayor en sentido negativo o igual a -3, al pasar al nivel -1 el máximo para pasar de nivel seria ahora -4.

Este es el código:

```py
val=-20 #se han ingresado -20 puntos al valor
max=-3 #maximo negativo para bajar de nivel negativo
nv= 0 #nivel principal, se necesitan -3 negativos en MAX para pasar a Nv -1 
# o +3 positivo en MAX para pasar a Nv +1, esto se logra cuando VAL es igual # a MAX. 

print("LA RESTA DE NIVEL")
while val <= max:
    print("ANTES Valor:", val, "Max:", max, "Nv:", nv) #ignorar
    nv-=1
    val-=max
    max-=1
    print("DESPUES Valor:",val,"Max:",max,"Nv:",nv) #ignorar

print("FINAL Valor:", val,"Max:",max, "Nv:", nv) #ignorar

val+=30 #Probando aumentar el nivel a positivo

print("LA SUMA DE NIVEL")
while max>=val*-1 and max<=0: 
    print("ANTES $$ Valor:", val, "Max:", max, "Nv:", nv)#ignorar
    nv+=1
    val+=max
    max+=1
    print("DESPUES $$ Valor:",val,"Max:",max,"Nv:",nv)#ignorar


print("FINAL $$ Valor:", val,"Max:",max, "Nv:", nv) #ignorar
```

Answer (score 2):

Revisando tu código, (sin tener en cuenta tu caso de uso porque lo desconozco, aunque entiendo que algún tipo de juego), no veo necesario hacer uso de un while, lo único que aporta a este caso es un consumo de CPU. Te propongo la siguiente alternativa basada en funciones y un control de flujo:

```
exp = 2 #Input de la experiencia, si es mayor que maxExp sube de nivel, si es inferior o igual a minExp, baja de nivel.

#Config
maxExp = 3 #Experiencia requerida para subir de nivel
minExp = -3 #Experiencia mínima para bajar de nivel

nv = 1 #Nivel. Está puesto a uno para que compruebes la bajada de nivel (tienes que tener un nivel superior a 0)


def lvlUp(): #Función para subir de nivel
    global nv
    nv += 1 #Subimos de nivel
    print(f'¡Felicidades! Has subido de nivel. Nivel actual: {nv}. Necesitarás {maxExp} de experiencia para subir al siguiente nivel.')

def lvlDown(lvl): #Función para bajar de nivel
    global nv
    if nv > 0:
        nv -= 1 #Bajamos de nivel
        print(f'Vaya! Has bajado de nivel. Nivel actual: {nv}. Necesitarás {maxExp} de experiencia para subir al siguiente nivel.')

def checkExp(exp): #Función lógica para determinar si sube o baja de nivel
    if exp <= minExp:
        lvlDown(nv)
    elif exp >= maxExp:
        lvlUp()
    else:
        pass #aquí puedes meter lógica en el caso de que siga en el mismo nivel después de hacer el check


checkExp(exp) #Llamamos a la función checkExp() para que compruebe la experiencia
```

De esta forma, te permite modularizar y reutilizar para evitar tener código duplicado.

Tienes el detalle en los comentarios, pero en general, el funcionamiento es al final muy similar al que nos comentabas:

1. Tengo definido un nivel actual, experiencia mínima para bajar y experiencia máxima para subir.
2. Entra una cantidad de experiencia (variable 'exp').
3. Se evalúa dicha experiencia.
4. Si es menor al mínimo (o igual) bajas de nivel. Si es mayor (o igual), subes de nivel.

Además, te propongo la siguiente alternativa:

```
exp = 120 #Input de la experiencia, si es mayor que maxExp sube de nivel, si es inferior o igual a minExp, baja de nivel.

#Config
maxExp = 120 #Experiencia máxima del nivel 1
minExp = -3 #Experiencia mínima general para bajar de nivel

nv = 1 #nivel principal, se necesitan -3 negativos en MAX para pasar a Nv -1 


def lvlUp(): #Función para subir de nivel
    global nv
    global maxExp
    nv += 1 #Subimos de nivel
    maxExp = nv * 120 #Aumentamos la experiencia necesaria para el siguiente nivel
    print(f'¡Felicidades! Has subido de nivel. Nivel actual: {nv}. Necesitarás {maxExp} de experiencia para subir al siguiente nivel.')

def lvlDown(lvl): #Función para bajar de nivel
    global nv
    if nv > 0:
        global maxExp
        nv -= 1 #Bajamos de nivel
        maxExp = maxExp / lvl #Modificamos la experiencia para volver a la del anterior nivel
        print(f'Vaya! Has bajado de nivel. Nivel actual: {nv}. Necesitarás {int(maxExp)} de experiencia para subir al siguiente nivel.')

def checkExp(exp): #Función lógica para determinar si sube o baja de nivel
    if exp <= minExp:
        lvlDown(nv)
    elif exp <= maxExp:
        lvlUp()
    else:
        pass #aquí puedes meter lógica en el caso de que siga en el mismo nivel después de hacer el check


checkExp(exp) #Llamamos a la función checkExp() para que compruebe la experiencia
```

En esta variante, la experiencia aumenta en función del nivel en el que estamos.

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar, el codigo funciona bien en el area de subir de nivel, pero no en el de bajar, trate de solucionarlo pero no comprendo su funcionamiento, no parece que haga lo mismo que subir pero al revés, me pregunto porque la funcion Lvdown envia NV cuando existe una global, y la parte de MaxExp=MaxExp / LvL, parece no funcionar correctamente.

Comment: La minExp deberia aumentar por igual pero en negativo, pienso que minExp es la clave que falta para solucionar el problema.

Comment: Buenas Joanky, para eso estamos!, ¿Que error o comportamiento no esperado te da el de bajar? la lógica es sencilla de lo que te pasé, el criterio de maxExp es la experiencia para subir y el minExp es la experiencia mínima que es cuando baja. La entrada de exp (ya sea positiva o negativa) se realiza en la variable de "exp", si ahí pones 3, sube de nivel, si pones -3 baja de nivel

Comment: es decir, está pensado para que solo tengas que tocar el exp para que funcione, y el maxExp y minExp para ajustar los criterios (por si quieres subir la experiencia requerida)

Comment: Y el "nv" pues para indicar el nivel del usuario (como lo tenías tu), coméntame si con esto te he resuelto la duda, si no, dame un poco más de detalle y estaré encantado de que lo ajustemos correctamente :)

Comment: Gracias, he mirado que el codigo no tiene recursividad, osea, en caso de que la experiencia supere el maximo no usa el residuo faltante para el siguiente nivel, osea, si el maximo es 3 y la experiencia es de 6, los tres sobrantes deberias sumarse al siguiente nivel, esto no sucede ni al sumar ni bajar de nivel, al bajar de nivel el minimo no aumenta en negativo, y tampoco se sube de nivel nivel en negativo.

Comment: @JoanKy Estoy haciendo algo parecido a lo tuyo y tampoco encuentro una formula, no soy muy experta así que esperare a ver que te responden.

Comment: @Lolita A lo mejor a ti te responden, creo que no me supe explicar.

Comment: Creare un tema con algo parecido talvez me respondan y te solucionen el problema.